# Prove that $f(x) = x^2 + x$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Using the definition of uniform continuity, prove that $f(x) = x^2 + x$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.

*Proof:* We have a function $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Note $\forall x,y\in\mathbb (0,1)$ that $|x+y| \le |x| + |y| < 2$. Set $\delta = \frac \epsilon 3$. Then for $x,y\in(0,1)$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, implies
\begin{split}
|x^2+x-(y^2+y)|&\le|x^2-y^2|+|x-y| \\ 
&= |x-y||x+y| + |x-y|\\
&=|x-y|(|x+y|+1)\\
&< |x-y|(2+1)\\
&= 3|x-y| \\
&<\epsilon.
\end{split}

Is this an ok proof?

Comment: the proof looks correct to me.

Comment: Note also that $3$ is the minimum possible denominator in the expression $\delta = \epsilon/3$, since $\sup_{[0, 1]} f'(x) = f'(1) = 3$ on this interval.